# How to pass data from Frag B to Frag A and also retain frag A's state when it is called again?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having two  fragments : Fragment A & Frag B.
I am adding Fragment B bu using this code in Fragment A:

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now what is happening is that when I am on Frag B and I want to come back to Frag A, I am using:

```
mActivity.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

(mActivity is my activity context)

It is indeed removing my current fragment and taking me back to Frag A (with all state in Views preserved)
but I am not able to pass any data from frag B to Frag A (which is a requirement)

Also, I tried using replace() function but then when I am going back to Frag A from Frag B it is creating the Views again and no state is retained. I am losing my data in the Views.

What should I do?

My requirement: to open Frag B from Frag A and once work on Frag B is done then pass the data from frag B to frag A and also to get back on Frag A with the state preserved as I left on Frag A (few values in Edittext)

Please help, I am new to Android.

Note: Somebody suggested me to use startActivityForResult instead of using frag B. Will that work? once the new Activity for result has finished will be back on frag A with all the states preserved? as it is happening when I am using popBackStack()?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the real "pass data between Fragments" you can use ModelView that holds variables/objects and then check its content when Fragments are loaded/attached.
In other words: each Fragment loads ModelView and read/write variables/objects as it needs, then prev/next Fragment (when Attached or Resumed) will change its content according to this ModelView content.

ModelView survives Activities "special destructions" (like when the screen is rotated and the Activity is destroyed and then re-crated immediately).

Example: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0